# What are non-numerical variables such as "Heads" and "Tails" officially called?

Tags: probability, reference-request, terminology, game-theory, word-problem

Is there a mathematical terminology for non-numerical variable such as

Head  Tail (referring to a coin flip) or  Rock Paper Scissors or Up/Down ?

---

For example, I want to say that my set $\mathcal{S} $ is filled with ______, where _______ are things like Head, Tail/ Left, Right/ Up, Down, etc. One such set is $\mathcal{S} $ = {Head, Tail}, another set is $\mathcal{S}$ = {Left, Right}, yet another set is $\mathcal{S}$ = {Happy, Sad, Mad}.

Note that I am not assuming a probability context. Non-numerical variables appear all over math, such as in game theory (Confess/Betray).

What should I use as the proper mathematical terminology in the above blanks:
States? Strings? Tokens? Literals? Symbols? Alphabets? Words?

Comment: How about events?

Comment: Categorical variables? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorical_variable

Comment: "Event" is good in the probability context, maybe not so good elsewhere. As you're going to be sticking these things into functions, you could call them *arguments*.

Comment: It depends on the context. For betray/confess you would use "actions". For head/tails you would use "results" or "events" or something similar. For $\Omega$ you can use "states" (as in states of the world), and so on.